Jackson's JSON compilation format issue
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 5)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
at [Source: (String)"�z��&�r#�$�3#Sb"; line: 1, column: 2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1851) ~[jackson-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:707) ~[jackson-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._throwInvalidSpace(ParserMinimalBase.java:685) ~[jackson-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2403) ~[jackson-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:672) ~[jackson-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4664) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4513) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3468) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3436) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.readValue(DefaultJwtParser.java:552) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
... 58 common frames omitted
搜索和尝试了许多，找不到具体的问题原因，请帮助我，谢谢
